# How to write a resolver for existing GraphQL schema in type-graphql?

Tags: typegraphql

When I work on a graphql project, I like the [type-graphql](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql) way: use classes and decorators to create GraphQL schemas.

But now I have a problem: we need to use some GraphQL schemas which are defined from another package. They don't use type-graphql, and provided some schema objects of GraphQLObjectType.

In type-graphql resolvers, it seems like we have to use the classes we defined by type-graphql decorators.

Is it possible to make them work together? How to write a resolver for existing GraphQL schema in type-graphql?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use some utils to merge the schemas:

https://github.com/Urigo/merge-graphql-schemas

TypeGraphQL was not designed to dynamically add fields to existing object types which are `graphql-js` constructs, not a class with proper types.